# aldeed tabular only counts elements of page

Tags: meteor, datatable

When i try to display the count of the count of the collection being used by Tabular , i only get the total per page .
here are my helpers:

```
  Template.audience.helpers({

  getAudienceCount: function(){
    return audiences.find({}).count();
  },
  getLikesCount: function(){
    count=0;
    audiences.find().forEach(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      count+=data.likes;
    });
    return count.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }});
```

calling those helpers in my template results in displaying different numbers for every page in the data table.

Update : 
tabular rewrites the subscriptions to collection that's what causes it to load only the current page element .
still haven't figured out a way to solve this issue .
also i haven't found a way to callback when tabular is done rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the same, but with [global helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

```
Template.registerHelper('getLikesCount', function () {
     count=0;
     audiences.find().forEach(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      count+=data.likes;
    });
    return count.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
});
```

Comment: still the same value is displayed , it seems to only find count the data of the current tabular page , and there no why to find on server side within a helper i since it's async

Comment: the `console.log(data)` what returns?

Comment: it just displays the data of the first page of Tabular (10 in my case) even audiences.find().count() on console , just returns 10 .

Comment: Yep the last day iwas talking with a dude, wich was having similar issue, seems like the package do the subscription for you, the creator of the package aldeed says thats that the reason of the project or the main reason, to show only the data required by the table and not the whole collection, **but** if you do the `count();` on the router and put it on a `Session`, it should work.